# Composer suggested approach for internal packages

Tags: php, tdd, domain-driven-design, laravel, composer-php

**Some background first**

Our company, a small startup with only four developers, is starting the refactoring of our products into reusable modules to simplify the development process, increase productivity and, along the way, we would like to introduce unit tests where fits.

As usual on a small startup, we can't afford wasting too much development time but, as we see, this is extremely important for the success of our business on a medium and long term.

Currently, we have two end-user products. Both are Laravel (PHP) applications built on top of our own internal business layer, mainly composed of webservices, restful apis and a huge database.

This business layer provides most of the data for these products, but each of them makes completely different use of it. We plan to build other products on the near future besides maintaining and improving those two that are almost finished.

For that to happen, we intend to abstract the common logic of those (and the future) products into reusable and decoupled modules. The obvious choice seems to be Composer, even with our little knowledge about it.

**Now to the real question**

I would like to ask other opinions on how to develop internal packages on a test driven fashion. Should each module be a composer package with it's own unit tests and requiring it's dependencies, or should we build a single package with each module namespaced?

To clarify a bit, we would like to have, for instance, a CurlWrapper module and that would be required on our InternalWebserviceAPI module (and a few others).

I personally like the idea of having completely separate packages for each module and declaring dependencies on composer.json, which would mentally enforce decoupling and would allow us to publish some of those packages as opensource someday. It also may simplify breaking changes on those modules because we could freeze it's version on the dependents that will need to be updated.

Although, I also think this separation may add a lot of complexity and may be harder to maintain and test, since each module would need to be a project on it's own and we don't have all that man power to keep track of so many small projects.

Is really Composer the ideal solution for our problem? If so, which would recommend: single package or multiple packages?

**Edit 1:**

I would like to point out that most of these modules are going to be:

- Libraries (ie obtaining an ID from an youtube URL or converting dates to "x seconds ago")
- Wrappers (like a chainable CURL wrapper)
- Facades (of our multiple webservices, those require the other two kinds)

Comment: I am currently thinking of a similar pattern to adopt for a Project. The questions I have are the same , so I would like to know how you went about doing it. Ideal solution I would like the the one Wouter has mentioned below , but as you know it adds a layer of complexity when it comes to the integration bit. But its a sound architecture for the long term. Although the trade off would be the Developers times , since this would be a bit time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, composer is the way to go and I recommend you to use single packages.

You don't know when you need these modules. It is better to create many single packages and be able to include them all (or a single one), than creating big packages and need to put more time in breaking a package in multiple ones when you need some classes from it.

For instance, see the Symfony2 project. That is a lot of components which are all required for the full-stack Symfony2 framework, but you can also use some components in your own project (like Drupal8 is doing). Moreover, Symfony2 gets more and more packages, it seems so usefull to have small packages that people put time in breaking some big packages in pieces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Wouter. Indeed Symfony and Laravel architectures were the main motivators of our doubt, they were built with modular packages in mind, which works pretty well, but they are maintained by not only dedicated developers, but an entire community. Or main fear is that this architecture may be overkill and consume too much maintenance time of our small team that is split between these products and our underlying services that provide the data for them.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using single packages: use [separate composer.json files](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#includes) for each subproject.

This has the benefit of letting you keep all of your libraries in the same repository. As you refactor the code, you can also partition autoload and dependencies by sub-library.

If you get to the point that you want to spin the library off into its own versioned package, you could go the final step and check it into its own repository.

Comment: This answer appears to be misleading - the link points to documentation on how to include repository configurations, not multiple composer.json - files.